# Access current user id on django model

Tags: django

I am overriding the save method on django model like this

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
```

I want to get the current logged in user id on the save method. I can get the currently logged in user id?

Comment: in your view `model.save(user=request.user)`. But maybe you doing something wrong, normally you shouldn't override `save` on model, you can use signals instead

Comment: I want to track and save every add, edit and delete in a table, if i use signal then it seems to be an unlimited loop as the save method itself will be called with in the signal.

Comment: why would it be an unlimited loop? give an example

Comment: on the pre_save signal, I want to save another object, i think it will also fire the pre_save function itself.

Comment: Thanks the pre_save works fine, but my question is, will able to access the user object form pre_save?

Comment: actually you can create custom signal and send it when you need to log user action - `your_custom_signal.send(sender=YourModel, instance=your_model_instance, user=request.user)` and do whatever you want in receiver. more here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signals/#defining-and-sending-signals

Answer (score 0):

Add in settings.py at MIDDLEWARE this line: 
'crum.CurrentRequestUserMiddleware',

Then in models.py:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        userid = crum.get_current_user()
        self.userid = userid.id
        super(PlantSpecies, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    userid = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, default=crum.get_current_user())
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Then in your forms template you can make the "userid" field hidden. If you look into your database you see that the current userid and date are automatically saed after submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the Model save method, you can use the save_model of Django ModelAdmin.

```
from django.contrib import admin

class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    obj.user = request.user
    super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Please follow the link for details

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model